# Sql - getting sum of a value in table for a specific id

Tags: sql, hive, sum

I have 2 tables

```
X                
-----------------
id      | value  
1       |    10  
2       |    20

Y
----------------
id     |    value
2      |      30
```

then the output should be

```
result
-----------------
id     |   value
1      |     10
2      |     50     (20 + 30) from both the tables
```

I have to do it in hive.

Comment: Can `id` be repeated in either table?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `left join`:

```
select x.id, (x.value + coalesce(y.value, 0)) as value
from x left join
     y
     on x.id = y.id
```

Comment: This approach would miss any ids in table y but not in x.

Comment: @Jabs . . . In the question *as asked* all the ids in the result set are in table X.  The simplest interpretation of the question is that is what the OP wants.  You may be correct, but you should ask this as a question to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below option with UNION ALL and GROUP BY-

```
SELECT id, SUM(value) Value 
FROM 
(
    SELECT id, value FROM X
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, value FROM Y
) A
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

If both the tables have mismatching list of ids, we can use full outer join to get the results. Please consider the below query:

```
select x.id,NVL(x.value,0)+NVL(y.value,0) value from x full outer join y on x.id=y.id;
```